# Regular expression to search for plural or singular of specific python

Tags: python, regex

I want to use a regular expression to search for dog or dogs in a certain sentence. Here is what I have but its not working. I need it to search for the specific word, not just a plural or singular of all words.

```
x = re.findall('(?<=\|)dog[s]?(?=\|)', txt)
```

Comment: Try `x = re.findall(r'\bdogs?\b', txt)`

Comment: No need to put a single character in a class - `dogs?` is just fine.

Comment: Oh wow, so the ? will only use the last character? For some reason I thought it would use the whole word lol Thank you

Comment: @HarpAngell: It uses the last *unit* - this can be a character or a group. With this in mind `dogs?` is different to `(?:dogs)?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quantifier is applied to the atom on the left. If it is a group, it will be applied to a group. If it is a literal symbol, it will be applied to this symbol.

So, `s?` matches 1 or 0 `s`.

Use

```
x = re.findall(r'\bdogs?\b', txt)
```

where `\b` are word boundaries, and `s` is optional.

Note: using raw string literals to define regex patterns are preferred in order to avoid issues related to escaping special regex metacharacters.

Comment: You might want to add that the `?` is greedy by default.

Comment: Though technically Jan fixed my problem. I thought that it would group the entire unit, not just the last unit. Thank you for your help though

Comment: @Jan: The greedy `?` (one or zero) and lazy `??` (zero or one) will work the same here since the pattern is anchored at the trailing word boundary. See [`\bdogs?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wD3dB5/1) and [`\bdogs??\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wD3dB5/2).